Communication Complexity of "2-Bit"
[For context, I'm trying to work through the derivation of Lemma 2.1 (2-Bit) here, https://users.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/papers/multiCC-soda12.pdf. ]
The '2-Bit' setup is that Alice draws a bit-string of length $n$ from a distribution $\zeta_p$, where each index is 1 with probability $p$, independently. Bob wishes to learn a subset $S \subset [n]$ of indices from Alice. So, if Alice has string $x = 01110$ and Bob as $S = 1, 2, 3$, a protocol should output $011$.
The main claim is that $E[D_{\zeta_p}^{1/3}(2-Bit)] = \Omega(np \log 1/p)$ -- so any protocol $\Pi$ to perform this communication must use at least $n p \log 1/p$ bits in expectation, up to constants.
I understand all steps in the derivation (in Appendix A), except for the statement $I(X; Y | \Pi) \leq \epsilon H(X)$, where random variables $X ,Y$ are Alice and Bob's strings, and $\Pi$ is the protocol, $\epsilon$ is the error rate. (Likewise, $I(X \Pi; Y\Pi) \geq (1 - \epsilon) H(X \Pi)$). It is said to follow because "with probability at least 1 − ε, we have Y = X, thus Bob knows X". Though it makes intuitive sense, I can't see how to derive it from the tools introduced.
More generally, how can we bound mutual information between $\{0, 1\}$ rv's using error rate, like this? The only tool I know is Fano's inequality, but that doesn't seem to give this result (in the binary case).

I added some more context, please let me know if it looks better now!
